# React Cannot read property 'id' of null

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

This is codesandbox I want to ask about -> https://codesandbox.io/s/2pwx46572n

When I click 'Add module' button it says 'Cannot read property 'id' of null'.
I believe the problem is in thematicArea.jsx component (components -> singleModuleComponent -> thematicArea.jsx) in line 42 (key={f.id}). It says it's null after 'Add module' click, but when I console.log it in line 32 it doesn't seem to be null. So...what the problem might be? Can anybody help me to fix this?

Below thematicArea.jsx code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SingleModule from "./singleModule";
import { Row } from "react-bootstrap";
import _ from "lodash";

class ThematicArea extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.takeModuleNameFromSingleModule = this.takeModuleNameFromSingleModule.bind(
      this
    );
  }
  takeModuleNameFromSingleModule(value) {
    this.props.moveModuleNameUpToApp(value);
  }

  orderedModules = _.groupBy(this.props.modules, thematicArea => {
    return thematicArea.thematicArea;
  });

  render() {
    console.log(this.orderedModules);
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <Row>
        <div>
          {
            (this.orderedModules = Object.keys(this.orderedModules).map(e => {
              return (
                <div key={e}>
                  <h3 key={e}>{e}</h3>
                  {/*console.log(
                    Object.values(this.orderedModules[e]).map(f => f.name + f.id)
                  )*/}
                  {Object.values(this.orderedModules[e]).map(f => (
                    <SingleModule
                      moveModuleNameUpToThematicArea={
                        this.takeModuleNameFromSingleModule
                      }
                      clickedModuleNames={this.props.clickedModuleNames}
                      chosenModulesNames={this.props.chosenModulesNames}
                      key={f.id}
                      {...f}
                    />
                  ))}
                </div>
              );
            }))
          }
        </div>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}

export default ThematicArea;
```

singleModule.jsx (here module is displayed)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ShowModuleDetails from "./showModuleDetails";
import AddModule from "./addModule";
import { Col } from "react-bootstrap";

class SingleModule extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.takeModuleNameFromAddModule = this.takeModuleNameFromAddModule.bind(
      this
    );
  }
  takeModuleNameFromAddModule(value) {
    this.props.moveModuleNameUpToThematicArea(value);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Col
        xs={12}
        md={6}
        lg={3}
        className={
          this.props.chosenModulesNames.includes(this.props.name) === true
            ? /*"single-module col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-2*/ "single-module single-module--added"
            : /*'single-module col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-2*/ "single-module single-module--not-added"
        }
      >
        <h4 className="sindgle-module__thematic-area-display">
          {this.props.thematicArea}
        </h4>
        <h3 className="single-module__module-name-display">
          {this.props.name}
        </h3>
        <div className="single-module__buttons">
          <ShowModuleDetails
            details={this.props.details}
            name={this.props.name}
          />

          <AddModule
            moveModuleNameUpToSingleModule={this.takeModuleNameFromAddModule}
            isAdded={this.isAdded}
            addNewModuleToList={this.handleAddNewModuleToList}
            name={this.props.name}
            clickedModuleNames={this.props.clickedModuleNames}
            chosenModulesNames={this.props.chosenModulesNames}
          />
        </div>
      </Col>
    );
  }
}

export default SingleModule;
```

And addModule.jsx (shows what happens after adding a module)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

class AddModule extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleAddModuleToList = this.handleAddModuleToList.bind(this);
  }

  handleAddModuleToList() {
    this.props.moveModuleNameUpToSingleModule(this.props.name);
  }

  isButtonDisabled = (chosenModulesNames, name) =>
    chosenModulesNames.includes(name);

  render() {
    const { chosenModulesNames, name } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          disabled={
            this.props.chosenModulesNames.length === 122
              ? true
              : this.isButtonDisabled(chosenModulesNames, name)
          }
          bsStyle="primary"
          onClick={this.handleAddModuleToList}
          className={
            this.isButtonDisabled(chosenModulesNames, name) === true
              ? "single-module__buttons--chosen"
              : "single-module__buttons--not-chosen"
          }
        >
          {this.isButtonDisabled(chosenModulesNames, name) === true
            ? "Dodano!"
            : "Dodaj moduł"}
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AddModule;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify `this.orderedModules` has data when it's being rendered like:

```
this.orderedModules && Object.keys(this.orderedModules).map(e => {
```

If everything works just fine in your current code, then you may also use:

```
key={f && f.id}
```

Comment: It works! But still don't know why :P 
Don't really understand what happens in that line of code - could you hint me where I can read what's happening here?
Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: before the data is mounted the render method runs and the data will be undefined or null and at that time you'll get error. To fix we're confirming to use only if they exists (not undefined not null)

Comment: Now it's very clear to me! Thanks again! You're great!